# Emacs for Windows error loading color theme

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I'm using emacs 24.3 on Windows 8. I have installed the solarized color theme from the marmalade repository, and am able to set it using <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> `load-theme`. It also sets for the current session when I use Customize, but doesn't load when I open emacs again.

I can open the customize menu and select the theme, but saving the changes does nothing, and nothing changes between that and my next session. I looked at several questions here about color themes, but most do not apply to Emacs 24, since I don't need to use `color-theme` to do it.

Below is a snippet from my `.emacs` file.

```
(custom-set-variables
  '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (solarized-dark)))
  '(custom-safe-themes (quote ("fc5fcb6f1f1c1bc01305694c59a1a861b008c534cae8d0e48e4d5e81ad718bc6" default)))
...
```

When I try to put `(load-theme 'solarized-dark t)` into my `.emacs`, I get the error:

```
error: Unable to find theme file for `solarized-dark'
```

I've checked the value of `custom-theme-load-path` after opening emacs and it includes the directory elpa uses to store the solarized theme. As mentioned above, I can load the theme manually, but something about loading it during init is breaking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add

(package-initialize)

To the top of your .emacs file and you are good to go.

Comment: This doesn't add themes to `custom-theme-load-path`

Comment: @Slomojo Color themes distributed as packages usually update `custom-theme-load-path` when loaded.  The theme in question [does so](https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs/blob/3c343dbbccc961947c6e6f24e32599aaf1f5ff65/solarized.el#L995).

Comment: Problem is 'usually' isn't anything to do with `package.el` it's completely down to the theme author.

Answer (score 0):

**Side note:** if the theme author has taken care of it, the theme will add itself to the `custom-theme-load-path`, however this is not a part of the `deftheme` and is down to individual theme authors implementing this behaviour.

To solve the problem, I made a quick snippet of emacslisp that will find packages with **theme** in their name, then add them to the `custom-theme-load-path` at startup.

Just add it near the top of your `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` (ie. before you `load-theme`

It has dependencies on `s.el` and `dash.el` (both available on elpa)

```
(require 'dash)
(require 's)

(-each
 (-map
  (lambda (item)
    (format "~/.emacs.d/elpa/%s" item))
  (-filter
   (lambda (item) (s-contains? "theme" item))
   (directory-files "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")))
 (lambda (item)
   (add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path item)))
```

Comment: This snippet is essentially superfluous:  Theme packages really should update `custom-theme-load-path` themselves, via autoloads, to be available right after `(package-initialize)`.

Comment: Should and DO are two different things, they don't, it's annoying, therefore script.

Comment: If a theme doesn't, it should be reported to its author as a bug.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the theme's folder has been added to `custom-theme-load-path`. The problem was that the packages were not loaded at the time I called `load-theme`.

Comment: @lunaryorn and in the meantime while you're waiting for x package authors to do a fix? - one mans superfluous is another mans "no more problem"

Comment: @Ryan sorry, I didn't notice that. I can remove the answer if you like.

Comment: No reason to delete this answer. For some people this could solve the problem.

Comment: I only suggested deleting because it solves a different problem. @Ryan